# how to generate a lazy loading module using angular cli

Tags: angular-cli, angular-routing

I have an existing angular cli application and I want to add a new module to my application which will be loaded lazily

I know angular cli provides command to generate modules which can be lazily loaded, what is the quick command I need to type to do below thing

- Generate a new module
- Generate default component to be loaded lazily
- Generate routing module for it and add default component to be loaded first
- Add routing for the lazy load module in main module

When I try `ng generate module module-name --route=app --routing=true`, it gives me below error

> Module option required when creating a lazy loaded routing module.

Comment: +1.  The error message tripped me as well.  I would have expected that if no `--module` is supplied, it would **default** to the `app.module`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Command:**

```
ng generate module new-module-name --module parent-module --routing true --route path-string
```

- **ng generate module module-name:** It will generate a module with name `new-module-name`.
- **--module parent-module:** The newly created module will be added into the parent module which is `app` module in most of the time.
- **--routing true:** Generate routing and a default component to be lazily loaded
- **--route path-string:** `path-string` will be added as a router in the parent-module routing config.

you will see the `angular-cli` output as

> CREATE src/app/modules/module-name/module-name-routing.module.ts (373
> bytes) CREATE src/app/modules/module-name/module-name.module.ts (400
> bytes) CREATE src/app/modules/module-name/module-name.component.scss
> (0 bytes) CREATE
> src/app/modules/module-name/module-name.component.html (29 bytes)
> CREATE src/app/modules/module-name/module-name.component.spec.ts (678
> bytes) CREATE src/app/modules/module-name/module-name.component.ts
> (301 bytes) UPDATE src/app/app-routing.module.ts (1398 bytes) Done

Comment: and what does the `--module app` do?

Comment: the route will be added to the --module param, in this case the the router will be added to the app module

Answer (score 13):

You can generate a lazy loaded module using below command:

```
ng generate module customers --route customers --module app.module
```

Excerpt from the angular documentation:
This creates a customers folder having the new lazy-loadable feature module CustomersModule defined in the customers.module.ts file and the routing module CustomersRoutingModule defined in the customers-routing.module.ts file. The command automatically declares the CustomersComponent and imports CustomersRoutingModule inside the new feature module.

Because the new module is meant to be lazy-loaded, the command does NOT add a reference to the new feature module in the application's root module file, app.module.ts. Instead, it adds the declared route, customers to the routes array declared in the module provided as the --module option.

For details refer to the official angular docs here: https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules